# Error Error: {'EXIT', {function_clause, [{rabbit_control_main,action,

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I am trying this command

```
rabbitmqctl eval '{ok, Q} = 
rabbit_amqqueue:lookup(rabbit_misc:r(<<"/">>, queue, <<"test">>)), 
[{pid, Pid}] = rabbit_amqqueue:info(Q, [pid]), exit(Pid, bang).'
```

to shut down a queue in order to generate NACK, but I am getting errors.

Comment: What's the actual error you are getting?

Comment: I get this standard error for eval function Error: {'EXIT',
           {function_clause,
               [{rabbit_control_main,action,